# Remove the horizontal start- and end-gap for headers and cells

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

[image: grid screenshot]

I want to remove the gap between column border and data. I simply want the data pressed up to the side, as it would in Excel. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure which theme you're using but looks like the default one is theme-alpine and in the examples this is the theme used. If so, you could override the `left-padding` property like this at the end of a CSS file:

```
.ag-theme-alpine .ag-header-cell,
.ag-theme-alpine .ag-header-group-cell {
        padding-left:  0px !important;
        padding-right: 0px !important;
}
```

For the other rows, it seems you can do it in the code and set the style in the columnDefs as follows:

```
// Create column definitions
const columnDefs = [
{
        // ...
        cellStyle: { 'padding-left': 0 }
        // ...
}]

// Create grid options
const gridOptions = {
        columnDefs: columnDefs,
};

// Grid creation
new agGrid.Grid(gridDiv, gridOptions);
```

If you're using Sass, there may be another possibility using theme parameters as described here, in particular this one:

```
// Horizontal padding for grid and header cells (vertical padding is not set explicitly, but inferred from row-height / header-height)
cell-horizontal-padding: ag-derived(grid-size, $times: 3),
```

**Reference**
https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/themes-customising/#customising-themes-using-css-rules

Answer (score 1):

AG Grid has different css custom properities to customize table styling specs.
you can override the default horizontal padding value for for both header and normal rows cells using the `--ag-cell-horizontal-padding` custom properity at the theme you are using.

```
  .ag-theme-alpine {
    --ag-cell-horizontal-padding: 0;
  }
```

Reference:
https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/global-style-customisation-compactness/